# \cal gives "Undefined control sequence" error

Tags: math-mode, errors

I've used `\cal` throughout my document and now when I go to switch the document class the `\cal` is giving me a "Undefined control sequence." error. Any thoughts on why the document class would make a difference?

Comment: Use `\mathcal{...}` instead. It should be possible to perform a global search-and-replace to achieve this. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: What documentclass did you use originally and which one did you switch to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define `\cal` by yourself, such as for example the `article` class does. In the `minimal` class it's undefined, and this way you can fix it:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\cal ABC$
\end{document}
```

[image]